# Use unix command inside awk commandline to process fields

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Is there a way to use unix command inside awk one-liner to do something and output the result on STDIN?

For example:

```
ls -lrt|awk '$8 !~ /:/ {system(date -d \"$6" "$7" "$8\" +"%Y%m%d")"|\t"$0}'
```

Comment: If you use GNU `awk` you might be able to use function `strftime` instead of running the `date` command. Please show some example output of `ls -lrt` and what output you want to get.

Comment: You might be interested in : `ls -lrt --time-style=full-iso` or `ls -lrt --time-style="+%FT%T"`. See `man ls` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing `ls`, which can cause several problems.
When you are trying to get your filenames order by last modification with yyyymmdd in front of it, you can look at

```
# not correct for some filenames
stat --format "%.10y %n" * | tr -d '-' | sort
```

The solution fails for filenames with `-`. One way to solve that is using

```
# Still not ok
stat --format "%.10y %n" * | sed -r 's/^(..)-(..)/\1\2/' | sort
```

This will fail for filenames with newlines.

```
touch -d "2019-09-01 12:00:00" "two
lines.txt"
```

shows some of the problems you can also see with `ls`.
How you should solve this depends on your exact requirements.
Example

```
find . -maxdepth 1  ! -name "[.]*" -printf '%TY%Tm%Td ' -print0 |
   sed 's#[.]/##g'|  tr "\n\0" "/\n" | sort
```

Explanation:
`maxdepth 1` Only look in current directory
`! -name "[.]*"` Ignore hidden files
`-printf '%TY%Tm%Td '` YYYYMMDD and space
`-print0` Don't use `\n` but NULL at the end of each result
`sed 's#[.]/##g'` Remove the path `./`
`tr "\n\0" "/\n"` Replace newlines in a filename with / and NULLs with newlines

After the sort you might want to `tr '|' '\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the output of the command, you can make use of `getline`:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{"date"|getline;print}'
Fri 15 Nov 2019 10:51:10 AM CET
```

You can also assign the output to an awk variable:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{"date"|getline v;print v}'        
Fri 15 Nov 2019 10:50:20 AM CET
```

Comment: Actually, the date command needs to be given input of fields from 'ls -lrt' output. the only other possibility I could think of is:

ls -lrt|awk '$8 !~ /:/ {print $6" "$7" "$8"|\t"$0}'|while read line;do echo "${line}";echo $(date -d "$(cut -d'|' -f1 <<< ${line})"  +"%Y%m%d"); done

But I need a cleaner approach.

Comment: @PraveenMishra the answer shows how can you get/print the output from external cmds in awk. Regarding which command, what parameter you want to pass, how to do further processing, it's your part. In your case, you can concatenate the `date` command with desired format options, and replace the simple `"date"` in the one-liner.

Comment: @PraveenMishra It would be easier to read your proposed command if you would add it to the question and format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to format the date output from `ls`.

The `find` [command](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ufind.htm) has extensive control over date and time output. Using `-printf` action.

For examples here:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r--. 1 cfrm cfrm 41 Nov 15 09:12 input.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 cfrm cfrm 67 Nov 15 09:13 script.awk

$ find . -printf "fileName=%f \t formatedDate-UTC=[%a] \t formatedDate-custom=[%AY-%Am-%Ad]\n"
fileName=.       formatedDate-UTC=[Fri Nov 15 09:43:32.0222415982 2019]          formatedDate-custom=[2019-11-15]
fileName=input.txt       formatedDate-UTC=[Fri Nov 15 09:12:33.0117279463 2019]          formatedDate-custom=[2019-11-15]
fileName=script.awk      formatedDate-UTC=[Fri Nov 15 09:13:38.0743189896 2019]          formatedDate-custom=[2019-11-15]
```

For sorting by timestamp, we can mark the sorting to start on the timestamp marker (`[` in the following example)

```
$ find . -printf "%f timestamp=[%AY%Am%Ad:%AT]\n" |sort -t [
22114 timestamp=[20190511:10:32:22.6453184660]
5530 timestamp=[20190506:01:03:01.2225343480]
5764 timestamp=[20190506:01:03:34.7107944450]
.font-unix timestamp=[20191115:13:27:01.8699219890]
hsperfdata_artemis timestamp=[20191115:13:27:01.8699219890]
hsperfdata_cfrm timestamp=[20191115:13:27:01.8709219730]
hsperfdata_elasticsearch timestamp=[20191115:13:27:01.8699219890]
.ICE-unix timestamp=[20191115:13:27:01.8699219890]
input.txt timestamp=[20191115:09:12:33.1172794630]
junk timestamp=[20191115:09:43:32.2224159820]
script.awk timestamp=[20191115:09:13:38.7431898960]
systemd-private-1a6c51334d6f4723b46fe5ca51b632c6-chronyd.service-AoZvZM timestamp=[20190516:05:09:51.1884573210]
systemd-private-1a6c51334d6f4723b46fe5ca51b632c6-vgauthd.service-f2m9rt timestamp=[20190516:05:09:51.1884573210]
systemd-private-1a6c51334d6f4723b46fe5ca51b632c6-vmtoolsd.service-0CJ32C timestamp=[20190516:05:09:51.1884573210]
.Test-unix timestamp=[20191115:13:27:01.8699219890]
. timestamp=[20191115:13:26:56.8770048750]
.X11-unix timestamp=[20191115:13:27:01.8699219890]
.XIM-unix timestamp=[20191115:13:27:01.8699219890]
```

Comment: OP uses `ls -rtl`, how do you sort the results without breaking filenames with a newline?